# Roboguice creates its own Application class instance

Tags: android, roboguice

I'm using Roboguice for DI in my project. As per android documentation only one instance of application can exists. But instances which crated by OS and by Roboguice is different.

How to force Roboguice inject application created by OS and disable creation of new instance?

Some code which illustrates situation below

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Application isn't initialized yet!");
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends RoboActivity {

    // roboApp and osApp two different objects but expected that roboApp the same as osApp        

    @Inject
    private MyApplication roboApp;

    private MyApplication osApp = MyApplication.getInstance();

}
```

Comment: How different? Maybe RoboApp is just inheritance of MyApplication? Or they cast to Application so you loose your custom variable? Something like this..

Comment: Nope, roboApp is the instance of MyApplication but it isn't properly initialized, because RoboGuice doesn't call onCreate during construction

Comment: Dmitriy, I had similar question to yours. In particular I was wondering if it is possible to have 2 instances of Application. Yes, it is possible. For example you can have Service running in different process alltogether and communicate with your app via IPC. Not sure how Robo works but it might be something like that..

Comment: Looks like this is a very common issue with roboguice.. someone worked it out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RoboGuice doesn't call `MyApplication.getInstance()` but will instead call `new MyApplication()`

You can write a Provider that calls `MyApplication.getInstance()` instead. This would look like:

```
 public MyAppProvider implements Provider<MyApplication> {
     @Override
     public MyApplication get() {
         return MyApplication.getInstance();
     }
 }
```

You can then bind this in your module like: `bind(MyApplication.class).toProvider(MyAppProvider.class);`